# Outlook HTTP Exchange Connection To Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, outlook

In Outlook, there is an option called "Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP".  We currently use this option with Exchange 2003 and it works just fine.

I have a case where I need to create an account to an Exchange 2007 server, but I'm being told that Exchange 2007 does not support the "connect using HTTP" feature.

Is this correct?  If Exchange 2007 does not support the HTTP connection, is there another means of remotely connecting to Exchange 2007 from Outlook?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using this feature on Exch2007, it uses RPC over HTTP and is called Outlook Anywhere . Here's [setup guide](http://www.exchange-genie.com/2008/02/configuring-outlook-anywhere-for-exchange-2007-sp1/) if you need one.

Comment: They just changed the name in 2007, the feature is definitely intact.

Comment: Yes indeed. you're right.

Comment: Thank you very much -- I would have been surprised if MS had actually eliminated this feature altogether.